# When building solution, ccrewrite fails with rewrite aborted due to metadata errors -> could not resolve type reference, fails on my machine only

Tags: c#, msbuild, code-contracts

I am having a really strange issue, when I try to build solution it fails

*The command ""(solution)\packages\DotNet.Contracts.1.10.20606.1\Bin\ccrewrite.exe" "@(project)ccrewrite.rsp"" exited with code -1.*

When I set detailed build output, I get some more information:

```
21>  Reading assembly 'xyz' from '(yyy)\bin\xyz.dll' resulted in errors.    
21>  ccrewrite : error : Rewrite aborted due to metadata errors. Check output window    
21>  Could not resolve type reference: [System.Web.Mvc]System.Web.Mvc.IClientValidatable.
```

**What I tried so far:**

1. clean, rebuild, deleting bin folder
2. upgrading Visual Studio to
   latest version
3. repairing Visual Studio version

Btw, if I am Building that xyz project - it builds without problems
From `manage nuget packages for solution` I see that `Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc` is only in that "xyz" project

[Seems like the same issue as here, but in my case it is VS 2017 and that question still has no answer...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038087/ccrewrite-fails-on-the-build-machine-due-to-nuget-references-having-contract-ass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, that project I was building which was failing when tried to ccrewrite for referenced library, had to have reference to `Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc` package (although this project did not use it by it self, but by some reason it needed it for ccrewrite because this package was used in that referenced library). When I added this package problem was resolved

**So, if you experience this issue**

1) Set detailed build output (`Tools`->`Options`, `Projects and Solutions`->`Build and Run`, `MSBuild project output verbosity`->`Detailed`)

2) check what is the error in Output window

3) if it is about problems resolving type reference - check installed packages for the project which is failing (*Reading assembly x from y most likely means, that y is missing some package which is installed for x*)